# How can I get the rank/position of the DynamoDB item?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a user leaderboard in dynamodb with GSI on lbId which is leaderboard id. It is as shown as below:

```
   {
  "TableName":"user_leaderboard",
  "AttributeDefinitions":[
    {
      "AttributeName":"id",
      "AttributeType":"S"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName":"lbId",
      "AttributeType":"S"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "score",
      "AttributeType": "N"
    }
  ],
  "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
    {
      "IndexName": "lb_index",
      "KeySchema": [
        {
          "AttributeName":"lbId",
          "KeyType": "HASH"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "score",
          "KeyType": "RANGE"
        }
      ],
      "Projection": {
        "ProjectionType": "ALL"
      },
      "ProvisionedThroughput":{
        "ReadCapacityUnits":1,
        "WriteCapacityUnits":1
      }
    }
  ],
  "KeySchema":[
    {
      "AttributeName":"id",
      "KeyType":"HASH"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName":"lbId",
      "KeyType":"RANGE"
    }
  ],
  "ProvisionedThroughput":{
    "ReadCapacityUnits":1,
    "WriteCapacityUnits":1
  }
}
```

Leaderboards have maximum 50-100 users in each leaderboard. I want to get specific user's rank or position. But Idk how can I do this ? Getting all users for one table, in this case user number is approximately 50-100 and get the index from array or is there any better way to do this ? I see many same or similar questions but there is no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. I'll make some assumptions. You want a specific users score/ranking for a specific leaderboard. Assuming `id` is your user identifier then you can simply do a `GetItem` from your base table.

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 'x' and lbId = 'Y'`

If you want the ranked users for a given leaderboard in order, then you can simply use a `Query` on your index.

`SELECT * FROM mytable.myindex WHERE lbId = 'Y' DESC`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't aware it is unclear. Let me open it: "id" is is user id, you are right. And lets say I have a table with 50 users. If I run Query on this table and get random user from table, I want also rank/position in this leaderboard.

Comment: Update: It didnt worked.

 partiQL := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM leaderboard_member.lb_index WHERE lbId = '%s' DESC", lbId)

 input := &dynamodb.ExecuteStatementInput{
  Statement: aws.String(partiQL),
 }

 result, err := l.userLeaderboard.Client().ExecuteStatement(input)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err.Error())
  return
 }

Error: ValidationException: Statement wasn't well formed, can't be processed: SELECT * FROM leaderboard_member.lb_index WHERE lbId = '1100' DESC

Comment: You use `leaderboard_member` but that's not the name of your table